# How to get the data-id value in this code

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

here i want to if i am select bangalore i want to take that value 1,suppose hydrabad means 2,i am trying but i am getting **undefined**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#resi_btn_search").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:1px;">
  <input list="options" type="text" class="form-control" style="border-radius:0px;height: 46px;" name="location12" id="location12" placeholder="City">
  <datalist id="options">
    <option data-id="1">Bangalore</option>
    <option data-id="2">hydrabad</option>
    <option data-id="3">Miredhpedia</option>
    <option data-id="3">Bangalore</option>
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit" id="resi_btn_search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside click event handler `this` refers to the clicked element and `$(this).data("id")` would try to get the data attribute value of clicked element which is `undefined`.

Update the datalist with value attribute and later you can get the selected option by using [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#resi_btn_search").click(function() {
    console.log($('#options option[value="' + $('#location12').val() + '"]').data('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:1px;">
  <input list="options" type="text" class="form-control" style="border-radius:0px;height: 46px;" name="location12" id="location12" placeholder="City">
  <datalist id="options">
    <option data-id="1" value="Bangalore" />
    <option data-id="2" value="hydrabad" />
    <option data-id="3" value="Miredhpedia" />
    <option data-id="3" value="Bangalore" />
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit" id="resi_btn_search">
</div>
```

---

Or you need to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to get the selected option using the input element value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#resi_btn_search").click(function() {
    console.log($('#options option').filter(function() {
      return $('#location12').val() == this.value;
    }).data("id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:1px;">
  <input list="options" type="text" class="form-control" style="border-radius:0px;height: 46px;" name="location12" id="location12" placeholder="City">
  <datalist id="options">
    <option data-id="1">Bangalore</option>
    <option data-id="2">hydrabad</option>
    <option data-id="3">Miredhpedia</option>
    <option data-id="3">Bangalore</option>
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit" id="resi_btn_search">
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it returns same id in Bangalore value?

Comment: @Ainz its data-id attribute is 3

Answer (score 2):

your options are in `$('#options').children()`:

```js
function SearchResiCtrl() {
  var $opts = $('#options').children();
  var input = $('#location12');
  var value = input.val().trim();
  
  var opts = Array
    .prototype
    .map
    .call($opts, function(el) {
      var label = el.textContent;
      
      return {
        id: el.dataset.id,
        label: label,
        isSelected: value === label
      };
    })
  ;
  
  var selected = opts.filter(function(o) {
    return o.isSelected;
  })[0] || null;
  
  console.log("options", opts);
  console.log("selected", selected);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  return $('#resi_btn_search').click(SearchResiCtrl);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:1px;">
  <input list="options" type="text" name="location12" id="location12" placeholder="City">
  
  <datalist id="options">
    <option data-id="1">Bangalore</option>
    <option data-id="2">hydrabad</option>
    <option data-id="3">Miredhpedia</option>
    <option data-id="3">Bangalore</option>
  </datalist>
  
  <input type="submit" id="resi_btn_search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {

$("#button").click(function() {
    var val = $('#item').val()
    var xyz = $('#items option').filter(function() {
        return this.value == val;
    }).data('xyz');
    var msg = xyz;
    alert(msg)

})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="items" id="item"/>

<datalist id="items">
  <option value="A item"  data-xyz = "1" selected="true">
  <option value="aa item" data-xyz = "2" >
  <option value="C item"  data-xyz = "3" >
  <option value="D item"  data-xyz = "4" >
  <option value="E item"  data-xyz = "5" >
  </datalist>
 <input type="button" id="button" value="Get xyz" />
```